# Calculate difference in days in a column based on multiple conditions in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
imo lf  max_fix_days    lf_diff_days    tc_end  is_tc_period    tc_end_diff is_sublet
8300523 3/5/07  180 NaT 9/1/07  1   NaT 0
8300523 1/3/08  NaN 304 days    1/3/08  0   124 days    0
8300523 3/14/08 NaN 71 days 3/14/08 0   71 days 0
8300523 3/6/09  NaN 357 days    3/6/09  0   357 days    0
8300523 7/16/09 150 132 days    12/13/09    1   282 days    0
9501851 7/25/09 390 NaT 8/19/10 1   NaT 0
9501851 9/20/09 NaN 57 days 9/20/09 0   -333 days   1
9501851 9/26/09 NaN 6 days  9/26/09 0   6 days  1
9501851 11/1/09 NaN 36 days 11/1/09 0   36 days 1
9501851 7/20/10 NaN 261 days    7/20/10 0   261 days    1
9501851 9/7/10  120 49 days 1/5/11  1   169 days    0
9501851 12/5/10 180 89 days 6/3/11  1   149 days    0
9501851 3/3/11  390 88 days 3/27/12 1   298 days    0
```

The overall objective is to produce the column 'is_sublet' (if you copy the data into Excel you can see it better). The data is a sample of ship transactions, some of which are on TC (ship is leased) or not given by 'is_tc_period' flag where 1=TC. 
'tc_end' tells you the end of the contract.

If the next transaction after a row with is_tc_period==1 has a date ('tc_end') that is before the tc_end of the row with the last TC, then it should indicate is_sublet==1. For example, the row with -333 days is correct, but the next row is not (it should calculate the days difference between 9/26/09 and the TC contract date 8/19/10, and repeat this until it gets to the next row where is_tc_period==1. If the days are negative, then is_sublet==1.

The calculations need to be performed by 'imo'.

I would like to create a function that does this for one imo, and then I can apply it to all of them but I am unfortunately stuck.

Current code is

```
 for index, row in gb_imo.iterrows():
  if row['is_tc_period']==1:
      date=row['tc_end']
      row['diff_from_tcp']=0
 else:    
    row['diff_from_tcp']=date-row['tc_end']
```

Comment: You should add whatever code you are using now.